# Opening a file in Rust using Windows API

Tags: winapi, rust

```
let mut file = OpenFile(dll_path.as_bytes_with_nul().as_ptr() as _, &mut ofstruct, 0) as *mut c_void;
let mut buffer_read: LPVOID = std::ptr::null_mut();

ReadFile(file, buffer_read, 5, std::ptr::null_mut(), std::ptr::null_mut());

println!("{:?}", buffer_read.is_null());
```

I'm having trouble finding the correct types for `buffer_read`, it's always null.

Comment: I don't know rust, but:  Don't you need to pass in an allocated piece of memory for the buffer?  Where do you allocate memory for the buffer?

Comment: The question is why. Why don't you just take the [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you *can* just link to the windows C [file API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) in Rust, does not mean you should. In particular, this robs you of a whole bunch of safeties granted by the language itself and mistakes made by you.

In particular, your code currently has UB, as passing `NULL` to the last two parameters of `ReadFile` simultaneously is a situation explicitly warned against:

> **lpNumberOfBytesRead**
>
> A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes read when using a synchronous hFile parameter. ReadFile sets this value to zero before doing any work or error checking. Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.
>
> This parameter can be NULL only when the **lpOverlapped** parameter is not NULL.

In your case, the idiomatic way of doing this safely is the following:

```
let mut buffer_read = vec![0, 5];
let fhandle = std::fs::File::open("path/to/your/file")?;
fhandle.read_exact(&mut buffer_read)?;
println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buffer_read));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
let mut buffer_read = vec![0; 5];

ReadFile(file, buffer_read.as_mut_ptr() as _, 5, std::ptr::null_mut(), std::ptr::null_mut());
println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buffer_read));
```